# Android encapsulation bug while reading in Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-viewmodel

I have set up a getter method in my `ViewModel` to get a Long-type field called `cWeek`. When I use the `value.getLong` inside the `addSnapshotListener`, it works and returns the value from the db but when I try to return it, the variable is null. I seriously have no idea what to search for to resolve this problem.

**Getter**

```
// this var is initialized in global scope
Long cWeek = getCWeek();

public Long getCWeek() {
        new References()
                .getUserRefDoc()
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Could not get cWeek data " + e);
                        }
                        Long var = (Long) value.get("cWeek");

                        cWeek = var;
                        Log.d(TAG, "cWeek: " + cWeek);
                    }
                });
        Log.d(TAG, "cWeek AFTER: " + cWeek);
        return cWeek;
    }
```

**Logcat:**

```
D/DashboardViewModel: cWeek AFTER: null
D/DashboardViewModel: cWeek: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`addSnapshotListener` is *asynchronous* and returns immediately, before the query is complete.  The callback you provide is invoked some time later.  Meanwhile, your code continues to execute, and the initial value of cWeek is returned while the query is still happening.

If you want to provide the results of a Firestore query (or any asynchronous function) from a ViewModel, you should return a LiveData that will deliver the final result.  The caller can observe the ViewModel for the result, to be received whenever it's ready.

Comment: but I am using the getter method, `getCWeek`, inside the viewmodel itself to power a different variable. And before, I had added this getter method in a normal java class, acting as a repository, it wasn't working then as well. So can you please give me a solution for the same? Nonetheless, thank you for answering!

Comment: OK, so your getter gets a single, incorrect value, and reuses it?  What is the behavior you're expecting that's different than what you're seeing?

Comment: my getter, inside the `addSnapshotListener` gets the correct value but when I store it in a global variable and return that variable, the value is null. I am trying to receive the value from firestore, and store it in a global variable but that is not happening.

Comment: You might want to read over my answer again.  The value you're returning from the getCWeek is different than the value you're printing inside the callback, because the query is **asynchronous**. and cWeek has not been set before its value is returned to the caller.  This is a very common mistake, and it requires that you understand how asynchronous function calls work with respect to the timing of your print statements.

Comment: yeah I get that but what should I do to actually get the results?

Comment: I gave you my advice in the answer.

Comment: but the return value of the getter is to be used in the view model itself, and I cannot do that.
Should I use an RxBus as an alternative to the ViewModel?